# Data being cut off when writing to a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which spellchecks words using a binary search. It compares the file to be spell checked to a file which is a dictionary and returns all mispelled words.

The spellchecker worked when i printed the misspelled words to the terminal but now im writing it to a file it is only finding a fraction of the words.

Iv also implemented a timer to time the search

```
import re
import time

start_time = time.time()
f1=open('writefile.txt', 'w+')

def binS(lo,hi,target):

    if (lo>=hi):
        return False
    mid = (lo+hi) // 2
    piv = words[mid]
    if piv==target:
       return True
    if piv<target:
       return binS(mid+1,hi,target)
    return binS(lo,mid,target)

words = [s.strip("\n").lower() for s in open("words10k.txt")] 
words.sort() # sort the list

text = open("shakespeare.txt" , encoding="utf8")
content = text.read().split(" ")
content = [item.lower() for item in content]
content = ' '.join(content)
content = re.findall("[a-z]+", content)

for w in content:
    if not binS(0,len(words),w):
       f1.write(w)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I had this segment of code before which worked by printing to the terminal. (also how could I write 1 word per line in the write out file)

`for w in content:
    if not binS(0,len(words),w):
      print(w)`

Search time by printing to the terminal : 2000 seconds

Search time by writing to a file        : 38 seconds

Comment: I have a suspicion that changing `f1.write(w)` to `f1.write(w+'\n')` will solve your problem. Can you please try that and report back?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see where you're closing the file after opening it. Writes to files are buffered, so that can be a reason.

A more proper way would be to use the `with` statement to close the file properly when you're done writing:

```
with open('writefile.txt', 'w+') as f1:
    for w in content:
        if not binS(0,len(words),w):
           f1.write(w)
```

---

In other news:

- try using a `set` to store `words`, so that you do efficient lookups: `if w not in words: ...`
- try rewriting the loop using `f1.writelines` and a generator expression

Comment: Using the 'with' and closing the file solved my problem, thanks.